# How to get dplyr `pull()` to recognize grouping in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(col1 = c("a", "a", "b", "b"),
             col2 = c(2, NA, 10, 8))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   col1   col2
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 a         2
#> 2 a        NA
#> 3 b        10
#> 4 b         8
```

I've got the data frame above that I'd like to perform the following logic on:

- Group by `col1`
- With this `col1` grouping determine the largest `col2` value
- Populate this largest `col2` value as the `col3` value, for said grouping

What you'd end up with is the data frame below.

```
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   col1   col2  col3
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a         2     2
#> 2 a        NA     2
#> 3 b        10    10
#> 4 b         8    10
```

My attempt at the code is below, and I understand it doesn't work because my `dplyr::pull()` isn't written (by me) in a way that it got the grouping logic I intend. How do I get `dplyr::pull()` to recognize the grouping I intend, or perhaps there's a better approach to solve my problem.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(col1) %>% 
  mutate(col3 = top_n(., 1, col2) %>% pull(col2))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   col1 [2]
#>   col1   col2  col3
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a         2     2
#> 2 a        NA    10
#> 3 b        10     2
#> 4 b         8    10
```

Comment: I think you're getting messed up by trying to use `dplyr` functions in places where base ones would suffice. `top_n` returns a data frame—if all you need is the 1 largest value of `col2`, why not just `max(col2)`? `pull` is the same as just `$` or `[[` and also not needed here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost close. The function to use is `max` which pulls the `maximum` value after removing the `NA`s

```r
df %>% 
group_by(col1) %>%
 mutate(col3 = max(col2, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   col1 [2]
#  col1   col2  col3
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a         2     2
#2 a        NA     2
#3 b        10    10
#4 b         8    10
```